# Creating multiple rows from one row of Excel Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

My data looks like this:

```
Parameter   Location_A   Location_B   Location_C  Location_D 
A           1            0.3          0.2         0.1
B           0.9          0.3          0.1         0.1
C           1.1          0.2          0.3         0.2
```

I have 365 parameters and 768 locations.

I want to create one row for each parameter and location combination and show the results in a third column (i.e., 365*768 = 280,320):

```
Location       Parameter     Result
Location_A     A             1
Location_A     B             0.9
Location_A     c             1.1
Location_B     A             0.3
Location_B     B             0.3
```

And so on.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I have a header row and then 365 rows for each parameters and column B thru ACO are locations.

I've looked through a few things but cannot seem to find the answer:
[How do I split one row into multiple rows with Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/633124/how-do-i-split-one-row-into-multiple-rows-with-excel)

[Splitting one Row with Multiple Columns into Multiple Rows](https://superuser.com/questions/1091576/splitting-one-row-with-multiple-columns-into-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 3):

Here we go.

### STEP 1:

Name ranges for convenience. PARAMETERS is the list of parameters from A2 on down; LOCATIONS is the list of locations, from B1 across; DATA is the large square from B2 to the end. See my example:
[image: NAMED RANGES]

### STEP 2:

In another sheet, set up your new table.
First column prints out all the locations, and it lists each location as many times as there are parameters:
[image: PRINT LOCATIONS IN FIRST COLUMN]

That formula:

```
=INDEX(LOCATIONS,ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/COUNTA(PARAMETERS),0))
```

That formula copies down.

### STEP 3:

Second column prints out all the parameters, and it lists each parameter once until there are no more to list (note that this count corresponds to the count of how many times to list each Location in Step 2). Now you've got your entire list of every location/parameter combination, once each:
[image: PRINT PARAMETERS IN SECOND COLUMN]

That formula:

```
=INDEX(PARAMETERS,MOD(ROW()-2,COUNTA(PARAMETERS))+1)
```

That formula copies down.

### STEP 4:

From here, the way forward should be clear - we're now working with a simple INDEX MATCH to find the data at the intersection of the given location and parameter.
[image: RETURN TABLE DATA FOR EACH RECORD]

That formula:

```
=INDEX(DATA,MATCH(B2,PARAMETERS,0),MATCH(A2,LOCATIONS,0))
```

That formula copies down.

### CONCLUSION:

With three formulas you've created your join table. Please consider selecting this answer so this question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

### NOTES:

- This works dynamically no matter how many columns/rows you have in your data (as long as you adjust the named ranges as needed, if you add more than the 365*768 records in this question's spec).
- It doesn't do anything special with missing or empty data, though; you could easily wrap the final INDEX MATCH in Step 4 with an IF(ISBLANK()) to return something more useful than '0'.
- This is NOT designed to skip those records, which adds a layer of complexity that's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in the result column:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(B7,$A$2:$A$4),MATCH(A7,$B$1:$E$1))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant at all, and offers the additional advantage that it doesn't work

Comment: @AlexM lmao, almost 2 years later. It's unfortunate that the user never responded. Regardless, I just copied the "Parameter" data in `A1:E4` and the "Location" data in `A6:C12`. Then just paste this formula literally anywhere, fill down, and it works flawlessly. It answers exactly the question asked with 1 step (instead of 4) and requires no additional sheets nor manipulation of the data (as you described). *drops mic*

Comment: I'm psyched you replied and I can barely believe that you still remember your process. Unfortunately, you missed a fundamental premise of the question: " I just copied ... the "Location" data in `A6:C12`" by which you mean you copied in the 5 lines of sample desired output the asker included, and operated off those answers provided to provide your answer. There's no need to use your formula to derive output from the input you used, because you used the desired output as input. May as well say "I coped the "Location" data in `A6:C12` and now your answers are in `C7:C12`".

Comment: (The answer as given is also unactionable without the additional information in the comment because copying reformatted data into `A6:C12` is totally arbitrary and not clear from the answer as given)