# Generate rows based on columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a starting table like this:

[image]

And I need to generate a row for each of the letters in the third column. What I did so far is to extract that info into separate columns, like this:

[image]

My goal is basically to get a table like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I thought about using a Pivot table, but I have no idea how and where to assign the different columns to in order to get what I need.

Note: I prefer not to use macros, as I have no experience using them, and I will have to do this kind of operation on a regular basis on different table structures, where the column "Letters" isn't as cut and dried as in my example (meaning I can't find out programmatically which row needs to be multiplied or not). I would have to rewrite the code constantly. I'd prefer if I could do it as a "regular" user.

Comment: I'm certain my method here https://superuser.com/questions/1185224/creating-multiple-rows-from-one-row-of-excel-data/1403367#1403367 can be adapted to this use case, but don't have time to write it out until tomorrow at the earliest. Give it a glance, and/or I'll try to remember to come back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit:  Screenshots added to assist in finding option locations***

Use `Get&Transform` from the `Data` tab.  Select `From Table/Range`

[image]

- The Power Query user interface will open
- Select the Letters Column and the option to Split Column by number of Characters (where the number of characters is one (1)).

[image]

- Select the Firstname and Lastname columns
- Select to UNpivot **other** columns.

[image]

- Delete the **Attribute** column created after the Unpivot.

[image]

- Close and Load

After you've done this once, you can add data to the table and re-run the query, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with this on `Sheet1`:

[image]

and run this macro:

```
Sub MakeReport()
    Dim k As Long, i As Long, N As Long, s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim v1 As String, v2 As String, lt As String, L As Long, ll As Long

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    k = 1
    For i = 2 To N
        v1 = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        v2 = s1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        lt = s1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        L = Len(lt)
        For ll = 1 To L
            s2.Cells(k, 1) = v1
            s2.Cells(k, 2).Value = v2
            s2.Cells(k, 3) = Mid(lt, ll, 1)
            k = k + 1
        Next ll
    Next i
End Sub
```

You will get this on `Sheet2`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I prefer if I didn't have to use macros (see edit).