# How to transpose multiple excel columns into rows and maintain structure

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data structure:

```
Country    # Sales 01.2019    # Sales 02.2019    # Sales 03.2019
France     42                 84                  21
Germany    10                 64                  12
Spain      29                 66                  43
```

And need to transpose it to this structure:

```
Country    Month     # Sales
France     01.2019   42     
France     02.2019   84        
France     03.2019   21     
Germany    01.2019   10  
Germany    02.2019   64
Germany    03.2019   12     
Spain      01.2019   29 
Spain      02.2019   66
Spain      03.2019   43
```

Is there an easy way to transpose such structures instead of copying everything manually to the desired structure?

Comment: asked and answered: https://superuser.com/questions/1185224/creating-multiple-rows-from-one-row-of-excel-data/1403367#1403367

Comment: Yeah, that was a new user who never selected the answer. Now it's forever unanswered because that user has become ghost.

Comment: I mean, nonetheless, it's a precise duplicate. Assuming named ranges, the formula given there copies to the worksheet in this question without modification.

Comment: @HackSlash No ghost here. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction and sorry for too little search from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pivot table. Pivot tables can be complicated and they are made using the GUI. It's best to see some visual tutorials. Give it a try, do some research and come back if you can't get it to work.

https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html